# AWS Cloudwatch event rule: Start and stop time

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

Is it possible to set start and stop time of cloudwatch event rules?
Use Case - I want to create a rule which triggers a lambda, but I want it to run at a specific date (every 2 minutes) and disable it at another date (these date interval can span across months).

As far as I know, when we create a rule (**rate (2 minutes)**), it starts running immediately. I can use this approach and in the lambda I can check if the current date is same as target date and proceed with lambda execution, and disable the rule when current date is greater than end date. Although, it might work but it does not seem the right approach since lambda would be unnecessarily executing until the target date.

Is there any way I can achieve the same thing without the hack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can set it to **specific date** only. For instance the following rule `0/2 0 28 9 ? 2020` would execute every **2 minutes** on `28 Sep 2020` only:

[image]

#### Update

To span across months, I think you need separate rules. For example you could define two rules to span date range 28 Sep to finish 5 Oct: `0/2 0 28-31 9 ? 2020` and `0/2 0 1-5 10 ? 2020`.

Comment: What if I want to start a job at - 28 sept and want to stop it on 5 Oct?

I tried this cron expression `(0 0/24 28-5 9-10 ? 2020)` but it also gives following triggers date of next month

`[Wed, 28 Oct 2020 00:00:00 GMT
Thu, 29 Oct 2020 00:00:00 GMT
Fri, 30 Oct 2020 00:00:00 GMT
Sat, 31 Oct 2020 00:00:00 GMT]`

Is it possible to stop the triggers on 5th and have no more subsequent triggers?

Comment: @TA- Could you edit your question and clarify exactly what you wish? As it is written now it indicates that you want only one day "a specific date (every 2 minutes) and disable it at the end of that particular date.", not a range of dates or some combination of different dates. In the worst case, you can create few rules for different dates.

Comment: Updated my question

Comment: @TA- I don't think you can span across months. I updated the answer. You would need to define two rules to span date range across two months, e.g. start 28 Sep and finish 15 Oct: `0/2 0 28-31 9 ? 2020` and `0/2 0 1-15 10 ? 2020`.